# How can I access files downloaded from Chrome on Android 11?

Tags: storage, file-permissions, android-11

With Android 11 adding scoped storage, I'm noticing I'm not able to access some key folders in my file manager app of choice (Solid Explorer).  In this case, files downloaded via Chrome and it's default save location (on SD). Even trying to open files within Chrome that requires an external app (such as PDFs) will fail and can not open these files. This effectively makes Chrome *useless* for downloading anything.

<strike>I am able to access Android/data in internal storage after granting permission, but not on my SD card.</strike> I can't access anything at all.

How can I access my downloaded files now (without rooting)?

I cannot access anything here. And looking at the downloads via Chrome, I cannot "move" files out, just "share" or delete them. And sharing does nothing at all, the file transfer will fail. "Sharing" to Solid Explorer does not work. What other options do I have?

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Galaxy S20+ (ATT)
Chrome 88.0.4324.181
Solid Explorer 2.8.9

Comment: Even sharing to Google drive doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of app, `2.8.8`. It let's you do that without root as long as you give permissions asked

Comment: I am on 2.8.8 but it's all the same. On internal storage, I can see the app folders but none of the files within, on SD I don't even see the folders.